# Inline function in React isn't running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, time, datetime-conversion

I am trying to convert a time string that is formatted as 24 hour into 12 hour. To do this, I created a function that will reformat then render it. However, when I place the function inline like `<span>{times && this.renderTime(times.StartTime)}</span>`in the correct location, nothing runs.

But, when I place the same function on a test button, it will run and log my newly formatted text. For example, `15:41` to `3:41 PM`.

```
  renderTime = time => e => {
    const hours = time.split(':')[0];
    const minutes = time.split(':')[1];
    let currentTime;

    if (+hours === 0) currentTime = `12:${minutes} AM`;
    else if (+hours < 10 && +hours > 0) currentTime = `${hours.split('')[1]}:${minutes} AM`;
    else if (+hours <= 11 && +hours > 9) currentTime = `${hours}:${minutes} AM`;
    else if (+hours === 12) currentTime = `12:${minutes} PM`;
    else currentTime = `${hours-12}:${minutes} PM`;

    console.log(currentTime);

    return <p>{currentTime}</p>
  }
```

Why will this function not run within the text

Comment: What's up with the `e =>` part? You are not using `e` anywhere. Why did you write the function like that?

Comment: Most of the time I create these functions, I don't want them to run immediately (passing values from an inline map into a function to submit to the server, such as an onChange on an input) but I don't want it to run without user input. Since I need to pass in information, `=> value => e` prevents it from running without user input. Essentially, force of habit instead of thinking through why I usually structure it that way.

Comment: *"I don't want them to run immediately"* Then don't call the function if you don't want it to run. A function doesn't execute on its own. It executes because you tell it to. To me it seems you should fix this at the callsite. But of course there are valid use cases for functions that return functions.

Comment: I want this one to return immediately but when you have an onChange, you do not want it to change unless if it changes. But, if you want to pass a value into the that function, then you need to call it with `()`. So if the function calls a function, it will only call the one that allows you to pass it into without running endlessly. So my issue what that I applied this across too many places (not appropriate for this render).

Comment: You can do that with `onChange={e => someFunction(someParameter, e)}` for example. Sure, what you do is not wrong. Just saying that there is more than one way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function is returning a function - change

```
time => e =>
```

to

```
time =>
```

Comment: soooo simple... instead I changed it to function(value)()

Comment: why do you need the extra function?

Comment: check my comment on the question, although I should remove it now

Comment: try to keep your code as simple as possible - in this case, there's no reason to return a function. Also, you can use `moment` to reduce it to `renderTime = time => (<p>{moment(time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('h:mm:ss A')}</p>);`